# 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
salary = []
names = []

def swap( A, x, y):
    tmp = A[x]
    tmp2 = E[x]
    A[x] = A[y]
    E[x] = E[y]
    A[y] = tmp
    E[y] = tmp2
```

Here I created a function to input two parallel arrays, which I use later to sort a list of salaries and names.

```
def floatInput():
    done = False
    while not done:
        nameIn = input("Please enter the employee name or * to finish: ")
        salaryIn = input("Please enter the salary in thousands for " + nameIn + ": ")
        try:
            salaryIn = float(salaryIn)            
        except:
            print("Program was expecting a positive integer or floating point number!")
            import sys
            sys.exit()
        if nameIn == "*":
           done = True
        else:
            salary.append(salaryIn)
            names.append(nameIn)
    return names, salary

    floatInput()
    print(names, salary)
```

Here is where I created a function to use bubble sorting on my two parallel arrays.

```
def bubblesort( A, E ):
    for i in range( len( A ) ):
        for k in range( len( A ) - 1):
            first = k
            second = k + 1

            if ( A[first] > A[second] ):
```

This is where I am getting my error that there are only 3 positional arguments but 4 were given.

```
            swap( A, first, second, E )

    print( A )
    temp = input("Hit Enter for the next stenp:/n")


bubblesort(names, salary)

print(names, salary)
```

Comment: Where do you define `swap`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it too include swap

Comment: You have defined `swap` to take 3 arguments - `def swap( A, x, y):`, and later You passed 4 to it - `swap( A, first, second, E )`

Comment: I see now, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to extend like:

```
def swap(A, x, y, E):
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your swap definition is missing the second array argument. It reads

```
def swap( A, x, y):
```

where I guess you meant :

```
def swap( A, x, y, E):
```